# Separation and Russell's paradox

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just want to be sure that I understand the connection between "Naive Comprehension", the Axiom of Separation, Russell's Paradox, and the existence of a universal set.  Is the following correct?

The Naive Comprehension Axiom has as an instance the following:
$$
\exists y\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow z\notin z)
$$
This entails:

y is an element of y just in case y is not an element of y
(where "just in case" means "iff")

which is a contradiction.

By contrast, the Axiom of Separation has as an instance the following:

$$
\forall x\exists y\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow (z\in x\land z\notin z)).
$$

The assumption that y is an element of y leads to contradiction.  But the assumption that y is not an element of y just entails that y is not an element of x.  So, we have shown that for every set, y, there is another not in it -- namely, y itself.  That is, there is no universal set.

Is this correct?

Comment: Note the commands $\exists$ (backslash exists) and $\forall$ (backslash forall), which will make your question much easier to read.

Comment: Not qqquite: All's well, until the 3rd to last sentence: "So, we have shown that for every set, y, there is another not in it -- namely, y itself." No — $y$ is constructed from $x$ using Separation. We have shown that for every set $x$ there is a set $y$ that is not in it. (Hence, there is no universal set.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct, but not quite: all is well, until the 3rd to last sentence: 
$$
\text{"So, we have shown that for every set, $y$, there is another not in it -- namely, $y$ itself."}
$$

No — $y$ is constructed from $x$ using Separation. What we can show is:

> For every set $x$ there is a set $y$ that is not a member of it: 
>   $$\forall x\exists y\, y\notin x.\tag{*}$$

We have this instance of Separation:
$$
\forall x\exists y\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow (z\in x\land z\notin z)). \tag{$SepInst$}
$$

Given $x$, there is some $y$ such that 
$$\forall z(z\in y\leftrightarrow (z\in x\land z\notin z)).
$$
In particular this holds for $z = y$:
$$y\in y\leftrightarrow (y\in x\land y\notin y)).\tag{$SepInst_{x,y}$}
$$

If $y\in y$, then by ($SepInst_{x,y}$) we have  $y\notin y$. As $(p\to\neg p)\to \neg p$ is a tautology, it follows that $y\notin y$.

*Thus, we can conclude now that $y$ is not the universal set. But that doesn't warrant the conclusion that no set contains everything: $y$ is hardly "arbitrary".*

Now, if $y\in x$, then the righthand side of ($SepInst_{x,y}$) holds, and the we can infer that the lefthand side holds too — that is, $y\in y$, which we have already shown to be false. So $y\notin x$ after all. $\,\square$

Notice that moving the inner negation in (*) outward, across the quantifiers, results in the logically equivalent sentence $\neg\exists x\forall y\, y\in x$, which clearly expresses "there is no universal set".

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Russell's paradox can be seen, in the presence of separation as the following theorem:

> For every set $A$, there is a set $B$ such that $B\subseteq A$ and $B\notin A$.

The theorem does not necessarily mean that $A=B$. But it does tell you that there is no universal set.

It is consistent with separation (and most other standard axioms of mathematics) that there is a set $A=\{A\}$. In that situation, the set obtained by Russell's paradox would be $\varnothing$, and indeed $\varnothing\notin A$. It is also possible for a set $X=\{X,\varnothing\}$ to exist, and I will leave it to you to figure out what subset of $X$ is not an element of $X$.

Comment: Got it -- thanks again!